# Should I use central logging if I am managing exceptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I'm running some Rails apps, and I'm using exception_notification gem. But I've recently found some other tools like Logstash and Graylog2 as a central log server.

My question is, would this be overkill for small applications, or is it good practice anyhow (taking into consideration I'm already managing exceptions)?

EDIT: ended up using [Airbrake](http://airbrake.io/).

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a whole lot of effort I would add the logging. It's definitely good practice and is a must for services. If your app is going to be constantly running you need logging so you have some info to work with when failures occur.

Comment: This is the confusion though. The exception notifier will give me details when errors occur, and if I need more info, I can dig into the logs on the server. However, I *rarely* need more info, and it would seem capturing all logging might be overkill for my needs.

Comment: @Zenph where do you consume the exception notifier? Is historical information available? ie can I view all the errors that occurred in the past 12 weeks? If not I would log my own errors. Also logging utilities generally have several levels of verbosity so you don't have to log everything. For example, you can limit it to warnings and errors.

Comment: The exception_notification gem sends out emails, so I guess it isn't optimal for large amounts of data (across many apps). I would probably have it route into my redmine install to collect everything. Thanks for the input. I can see where you're coming from.

Comment: @Zenph Like I said it may not be necessary but it's definitely good practice. If your service ends up becoming highly utilized you're going to want logs that have some permanence and when an error is discovered (say a bug that isn't a major issue and is going to take two weeks to fix) you don't want to get 20 emails a day about it.